# Magento2 adminhtml theme not loading for custom module

Tags: adminhtml, magento2, theme

I have a custom module that should show a grid in adminhtml with items that can be clicked and edited. 
adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="ustorelocator" frontName="ustorelocator">
            <module name="Unirgy_StoreLocator" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Action code is:

```
<?php
namespace Unirgy\StoreLocator\Controller\Adminhtml\Locations;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class ListAction extends Action
{

/**
 * Dispatch request
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
 */
public function execute()
{
    // TODO: Implement execute() method.
    //echo "loaded";
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
    // $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Unirgy_StoreLocator::locations');
    $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Store Locations'), __('Store Locations'));
    $resultPage->addBreadcrumb(__('Manage Store Locations'), __('Manage Store Locations'));
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Blog Posts'));
    return $resultPage;
    //$this->_setActiveMenu("Store Locations");
  }
}
```

Routing works fine, action is executed, but when reaching a line that sets active menu, it dies with fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setActive() on a non-object in
/app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php on line 60
```

After some debugging I found that simply backend theme is not being loaded. Anyone have any ideas what I can be missing? I can post the entire error log if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently running DI compilation fixes the problem. 
`php -d memory_limit=1024M -f bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant` did it for me in this case.